# Crystal Reports 2011 on Windows 8

Tags: crystal-reports

I have searched high and low for this info to no avail. I was was wondering if anyone knows if you can install CR2011 on Win8 machine. My company purchased CR2011 last year but we never used it and now I have come to use it, my laptop has been updated to Win8. All the documentation I have found mentions up to Win7.
Thanks for any help
Ian

Comment: I'd be really surprised if you couldn't. I'd just try it, see how it goes, and if you run into problems try installing in [Windows 7 compatibility mode](http://techmell.net/how-to/run-programs-compatibility-mode-windows-8/)

Comment: I found out that win 8 supports the downloadable VS2010 Crystal Reports